# Nested form problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some code:

index.html.haml:

```
= form_tag 'search/index', :id => "index_form" do
  /* some fields there */
  = render :partial => 'geo_form', :object => @geo
  = submit_tag 'Search'
```

_geo_form.html.haml:

```
= form_tag 'search/save_geo', :id => "geo_form" do
  /* some fields there */
  = submit_tag 'Accept'
```

The problem is: when I complete the second(nested) form and press the 'Accept' button, rails process the first form. How can I get a program to process the second form after clicking 'Accept' button. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `field_for` method for nested forms.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use `fields_for`. It doesn't actually create a new form tag, but arranges the field names so that the you can call @model.update_attributes(params[:model]) and **both** models will be updated (assuming they have some sort of ActiveRecord relationship like `:has_many` or `:belongs_to`)

The code will look something like this:

```
form_for @my_model1 do |f|
    f.text_field :name
    f.fields_for @my_nested_model do |nested|
        nested.text_field :start_date
```

You can find great detail in this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1